# Can linux sed efficiently replace entire line, with backreferences?

Tags: linux, sed

I'm using the `sed` `s/regex/replacement/g` command a lot, but often I find myself wanting to replace the *whole line* with a combination of the matched portions. For example:

```
sed -rn 's/.*something([^ ]+) .*/\1/gp' log.txt
```

The above outputs *just matching lines* (automatic printing of pattern space is suppressed with `-n`) and those lines are replaced with the first space-delimited token that follows `something`.

When working with large files, however, this is unnecessarily slow because the `.*` part at the beginning will initially match anything, and once a match is found, matching continues with the trailing `.*`. But notice these `.*` parts are only needed to replace the whole line, not for the matching itself.

Is there a way to tell `sed` to replace the *entire line* despite *not having matched* the entire line? I tried using the 'c' command (replace line) but it seems does not use backreferences:

```
sed -rn '/something([^ ]+) /c\ \1' log.txt
```

The `\1` does not work.

**Edit**: The `grep -o 'something.*'` is 6 times faster than the corresponding `sed` command that removes the line prefix using `.*`.

Comment: No, so, use `grep -Po 'something\K\S+' log.txt`

Comment: Did you try with `'/something/s/.*something([^ ]+) .*/\1/gp`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet not a bad idea but didn't make it faster. Editing the question with comments on performance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not possible to match a part of a line, and replace non-matched parts of it.

Replacing with any tool means *consuming* (reading matched text into buffer and advancing the regex index) text that matches a pattern and replacing only the consumed part with the provided replacement pattern.

**What has not been consumed is not affected by regex replace operation**.

Thus, the solution is to make sure you match and consume the whole part of a text you want to replace.

Since using `.*` in any place before the end of a pattern is a costly thing (`.*` at the end is usually fast), you are right it is a good idea to resort to alternate ways to extract the text you want.

In Linux, GNU `grep` can be used:

```sh
grep -Po 'something\K\S+' log.txt
```

where `something` matches and consumes `something` text, `\K` omits the text from the match, and `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace chars.

Also, with `sed`, you can minimize the impact of `.*` use when you first check for the specific pattern:

```sh
sed -nE '/something[^ ]+ /s/.*something([^ ]+) .*/\1/p' file
```

The `something[^ ]+`  part can be checked for faster, and thus, only matching lines will have to be processed with a costlier pattern. **Note** this won't be any better if a lot of lines contain `something` + one or more non-spaces + space.

Comment: Yes but your `grep` suggestion is too tailored on this example. And the `sed '/something/s...` does not help with performance.

Comment: @haelix If you need something more generic, please consider editing your question and providing a more generic description of your goal.

Comment: @haelix Those are not solutions but workarounds, because there is no solution you expect. So, `grep` workaround may be tailored for *any* scenario you can imagine. If you need a specific scenario, please showcase it in the question.